# If $f$ and $g$ are measurable and well-defined a.e., show $f+g$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

The question is

> If $f$ and $g$ are measurable and well-defined a.e., show $f+g$ is measurable.

I can show that the case when $f+g$ are well-defined everywhere.

Let $\Omega_{f+g>a}=\{x\in \Omega:f(x)+g(x)>a\}$, then $\Omega_{f+g>a}=\Omega_{f>a-g}$.

There is a theorem in my text book saying that if $f$ is measurable then $\Omega_{f+a}$ is measurable for any real number $a$.

Another theorem states that if both $f,g$ are measurable, then $\Omega_{f>g}$ is measurable.

As a result $\Omega_{f>a-g}$ is measurable, hence $\Omega_{f+g>a}$ is measurable, then $f+g$ is measurable.

Can anyone help with the case when $f,g$ are well-defined a.e. respectively? Thank you!

Comment: The well defined a.e. case occurs when $f(x)=-g(x)=\pm\infty$. This is a set, say $A$ of measure zero, so you just need to check that $h(x)=g(x)+f(x), x\not\in A$, $h(x)=0, x\in A$ is measurable and $h=f+g$ a.e., so $f+g$ is measurable.

Comment: What do you mean by "well-defined a.e."? That $f,g$ are finite a.e.?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "well defined a.e."? How do you define the sum of non-well-defined functions? How do you define measurability of non-well-defined functions? Do you assume that your measure space is complete? Do you know/assume that if you define $f(x) := 0$ for those $x$ at which $f(x)$ is not "well-defined" that the resulting function $f$ is measurable?

Comment: Yes when $f$ is well-defined a.e. it means $f$ is finite a.e.. Well, I realized that $f,g$ are well-defined a.e. then it means $f+g$ are well-defined a.e. Say $f+g$ is not well-defined on $Z$, then $|Z|=0$, $\Omega - Z$ is measurable, and $f+g$ are well defined everywhere on $\Omega - Z$. Since $f,g$ are measurable on $\Omega$, then they are measurable on $\Omega - Z$, then we apply the above technique. Please help verify this proof.

Comment: Looks good to me.